# Play app is not generating logs folder

Tags: java, logging, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a play project which doesn't contain any logs folder or may be it was deleted by me but when i tried running it by command play run, it doesn't auto generated that logs folder and application.log, when i manually created that folder and file (application.log) and run the app again that file was deleted, and it is working fine in my other two play project. In that project if i delete logs file and run the project by play run it gets created automatically.my play app is not generating logs folder. May i know why i am facing this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution , i have included the jar of sl4j from myside , i think play also provide this jar, so it was the reason for this problem.